# CSV file (with special characters) upload encoding issue

Tags: servlets, csv, character-encoding, apache-commons-fileupload

I am trying to upload a CSV file that has special characters using ServletFileUpload of apache common. But the special characters present in the CSV are being stored as junk characters in the database. The special characters I have are Trademark, registered etc. Following is the code snippet.

```
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    FileItemStream item = iter.next();
    String name = item.getFieldName();
    InputStream stream = item.openStream();
    if (item.isFormField()) {
        System.out.println("Form field " + name + " with value "
            + Streams.asString(stream, "UTF-8") + " detected.");
    }
}
```

I have tried reading it using BufferendReader, used request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"), tried upload.setHeaderEncoding("UTF-8") and also checked with IOUtils.copy() method, but none of them worked.

Please advice how to get rid of this issue and where it needs to be addressed? Is there anything I need to do beyond servlet code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What database are using? What character set is database using? Characters can be malformed in the database rather than in Java code.

Comment: I am using oracle. Database character set should be fine as special characters are working in other parts of the application.